# ArcGIS Online Field Maps Grey Out Funciton

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, arcgis-field-maps

I am wanting to create an editable point layer for the field techs. When they go out into the field and confirm a point, I would like the point to grey out on the fieldmap/webmap.

Does field maps/webmaps have this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to create a symbology where an unvisited point is say black and a visited is greyed out. You would have a text field to record Yes or No for visit. It would be up to your field worker to edit this value. A simple Domain on the field would do that.